# DialogFragment not recognizing finish() method

Tags: java, android, fragment, onclicklistener, android-dialogfragment

Hello ultimately what I am looking to do is to have a DialogFragment show on screen to confirm that the user wants to exit the app. If the user says that they do wish to close the app the app shuts down. If the user does not the DialogFragment goes away.

I have seen the finish() method called in the onClick method. However this does not work for me.

```
exitDialog.setPositiveButton("Shutdown", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Exit the app.
           finish();
        }
    });
```

The error that I get is that "finish()" cannot be resolved. I am wondering if the issue has to do with the fact that I am using finish() in a DialogFragment class? Or is it something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments don't have `finish()`. You probably want to finish the whole activity:

```
getActivity().finish()
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. However when I click on the center button of the Samsung Galaxy S4 Active (testing on this device) it still shows up in the list of recent apps and when you look at the details for the app it has force stop as not greyed out. Does that mean that the app is still running/is the close reflected in the logCat?

Comment: @AlecSherwood Android apps don't "exit" - you shouldn't expect them to be running or not running at particular times.

Comment: Ok ultimately if I use finish() will the app stop collecting location data and stop using device resources?

Comment: If you call `finish`, you destroy your activity. Android does not guarantee if the application would be stopped or not by doing that nor does it guarantee anything about recent activities; they may be alive and they may not be alive (if they are not and the user switches to them, they are automatically created). Whether location data are no longer collected depens on whether you correctly stop doing that in `onStop` (you should not collect them after `onStop`; if you want to collect data in background, you should use a service and stop collecting data by stopping the service).

Answer (score 1):

finish() is a method that belongs to the Activity.

Try using :

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

1. getDialog().dismiss();  to close the dialog
2. getActivity().finish(); to finish the current Activity.